# I want to use OnTriggerNotTouching() like OnTriggerStay()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public a;
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    a = true;
}
```

This code makes a true while touching and false when away,

If this hit other collider suddenly disappears with Destroy(),
OnTriggerExit() is not called and a always becomes true.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{}else{}
```

It would be easier if I could do that ...

Is there such a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FixedUpdate` is executed before `OnTriggerStay` and `WaitForFixedUpdate` is executed after it, combined use them to simulate an untouched event.

```
bool a;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    a = false;
    StartCoroutine(OnTriggerNotTouching());
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    a = true;
    Debug.Log("Touching");
}

IEnumerator OnTriggerNotTouching()
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    if(!a)
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Touching");
    }
}
```